# MenuBarItem only for MacCatalyst. Render for Windows is not great

Tags: maui

In my XAML page for MAUI, I added a `MenuBarItems` like that

```
<ContentPage.MenuBarItems>
    <MenuBarItem Text="File">
        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Exit"
                        Command="{Binding ExitCommand}" />
    </MenuBarItem>
    <MenuBarItem Text="{lang:Translate Title}">
        <MenuFlyoutSeparator />
        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="{lang:Translate Add}"
                        Command="{Binding AddLocationCommand}" />
    </MenuBarItem>
    <MenuBarItem Text="View">
        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Refresh"
                        Command="{Binding RefreshCommand}" />
    </MenuBarItem>
</ContentPage.MenuBarItems>
```

The render of this menu for Windows is not great. As you can see in the following screenshots, the menu is displaying on top of the page title bar and the `ToolbarItems` that displays the icon at the end.

[image]

[image]

It is working as expected for MacCatalyst and I like to keep it. Is there a way to display the menu only for MacCatalyst? My first idea was to add a property in the *ViewModel*. Maybe there is a nice different way like `OnPlatform`.

Comment: It would be feasible if we can create the `MenuBarItem` in code behind and the use [Conditional compilation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/invoke-platform-code#conditional-compilation) to only render the  `MenuBarItem` on `MacCatalyst` or use `
if(Microsoft.Maui.Devices.DeviceInfo.Platform== DevicePlatform.MacCatalyst) 
 { //then create the menubar item}` .